# ExecutorService state Listener

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am currently building an application that polls some data over a Wireless Sensor Network and process them afterwards to extract the necessary information.

I use an `ExecutorService` to run the polling Task multiple times (as many as the nodes in the network).

There will be a status `Label` in the GUI that will print the statuses of the `ExecutorService`. The statuses will be:

- Polling node 1 (2, 3, 4, n)...
- Terminating threads...
- Polling completed

I post a snippet of the `ExecutorService`code below.

My problem is that "Polling finished" is printed in every single thread that is being stopped and not at the end; while `ExecutorService` is being shutting down. This is obvious, since every thread runs in parallel with the others.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

```
threadPool.shutdown();
```

executes as soon as all the running threads have been finished.

I have to find a way to check/listen to the current state of the `ExecutorService` and when enters the `shutdown` state to print the status label.

Any advise would be highly appreciated.

```
public class ScannerThread extends Thread {
    ...
    private static final int NUM_OF_THREADS = Nodes.COUNT;
    private static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 200;
    private ExecutorService threadPool;

    public ScannerThread() {
        threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_OF_THREADS);
        ...
        setDaemon(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // poll data from each node in parallel, in a separate thread
        for (Node node : Nodes.COUNT) {
            ...
            PollingTask task = new PollingTask(node.getID());
            threadPool. execute(task);
        }

        // request shutdown of the thread pool
        threadPool.shutdown();

        try {           
            // wait for all threads that are currently running
            while (!threadPool.awaitTermination(UPDATE_INTERVAL, MILLISECONDS)) {
                statusLabel.setText("Terminating threads...");
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // polling completed
            statusLabel.setText("Polling completed");
        }


    class PollingTask implements Runnable {
       ...
       private String noteID;

       PollingTask(String id) {
           noteID = id;
           ...
       }

       @Override
       public void run() {
           ...
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: "My problem is that "Polling finished" is printed in every single thread" - Did you mean Polling Completed? How can this be printed by every thread? This should be printed only by ScannerThread and there would be only one ScannerThread. The threads in the pool run the PollingTask and unless you print a "Polling Completed" within these tasks there is no way that you would see a "Polling Completed" for each thread that is a part of the thread pool.

Comment: I'm sorry. Yes, my typo. I did mean "Polling Completed". While ExecutorService is running the active threads, every single thread executes its run() and gets finished. So, in my code the status Label prints: Scanning node 1 -> Terminating threads -> Scanning node 2 -> Terminating threads -> Scanning node n -> Terminating threads.
But, I want Scanning node 1 -> Scanning node 2 -> Scanning node n -> Terminating threads -> Polling Completed; which is when ExecutorService has been shut down.

Comment: while (!threadPool.awaitTermination(UPDATE_INTERVAL,MILLISECONDS)) {
                statusLabel.setText("Terminating threads...");}  --- Here you are waiting for UPDATE_INTERVAL milliseconds and printing "Terminating Threads". This would be printed every time the blocking call awaitTermination times out and this is not necessarily printed once for each of the threads in the thread pool...so if two threads are terminated while you are in this blocking call, it will print 'Terminating Threads' only once after the awaitTermination() times out...

Comment: I guess your problem is that you want "Terminating Threads" to be printed only once. You can move the statusLabel.setText("Terminating threads..."); outside of the while loop and have nothing inside the while body right...i am still not sure if I understand your problem correctly.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My code there is wrong for what I am trying to do. This try-catch block is only needed to update the status label when "Polling Completed". But the other part about "Terminating Threads' is wrong. But,  threads in the pool execute and terminate themselves each one in the queue and not alltogether when ExecutorService.shutdown(). So, I need to find another way to check/listen when ExecutorService is being shut down and finishes any remaining threads. Am I right?

Comment: To clearly understand what I am trying to do you can use a Network Scanner like Angry IP Scanner... While scanning the hosts in network it displays "Scanning <host_ip>..." and when is finished it displays "Wait for all threads to terminate"...

Comment: Why wouldn't this work? http://pastebin.com/tt7unZUn

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109594/discussion-between-john-astralidis-and-user3493289).